# feednix SegFault on lubuntu 18.04

Tags: lubuntu, segmentation-fault, rss

After compiling & installing the feednix project (Lubuntu 18.04) it is fall in the SegFault.

```
$ feednix
Aborted
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I create ~/.config/feednix/config.json with User-Id & token also copy it to /etc/xdg/feednix

This problem appears in 4 forks of feednix I had checked

```
$ uname -a
Linux small-note 4.14.144-0414144-generic #201909160828 SMP Mon Sep 16 08:30:48 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is someone use it last years? It looks cool but abandoned and recursively forked.

Thank you for the help

Comment: "Segmentation fault" is Linux's way of telling you that the program has tried to access unallocated memory (location 0, or beyond your highest address), often because of a bad pointer. Since you have the source, you should be able to find the problem. Check the documentation that came with the source to see if there's an easy way to turn on debugging. Run `feednix` under a debugger (`gdb`), or run it via `strace feednix`. Look for crash dump info in `/var/crash` . Read `man 5 core`.

Comment: I KNOW what is this and how to deal with it including the debugging. The question was about feednix situation at this moment and finding the persons who use it now.